# Make effect only on hovered element in JQuery. - Same classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="box a">
    <div class="box b">
        <div class="box c">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box d">

    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to make the following: If I hover just over the largest box a, I want to make some effects on it, like opacity for example.

BUT, if I hover on box c (which is in box a and b) I only want to make the opacity effect on box c.

What I tried was:

```
$('.box').mouseenter(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css({'opacity': 0});
}).mouseleave(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css({'opacity': 1});
});
```

But this doesnt work. Does anyone know a solution?

I tried it with both, JS and CSS and both times couldnt figure it out. It would be really helpful to see both solutions here.

Comment: shouldn't you select .box.c for its effects?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) & [mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)

```
$('.box').mouseover(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css({
        'opacity': .25
    });
}).mouseout(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css({
        'opacity': 1
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/43Mda/)

Why, look at the mdn documentation for [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseenter) and [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseleave)

Comment: can you tell me why hover not work like your code but they are same

Comment: $('.box').hover(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).css({'opacity': 0});
    },function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).css({'opacity': 1});
    }); like this

Comment: @Riturajratan not the same... look at the mdn docs... hover registers mouseenter and mouseleave handlers they are not the same as mouseover and mouseout

Answer (score 0):

Try this to your script

```
$('.c').mouseenter(function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
$(this).css({'opacity': 0});
}).mouseleave(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css({'opacity': 1});
});
```

Comment: if i mouseover on a, the other 2 dont disappear, its wrong, thanks anyhow

Answer (score 0):

it is because of the classes you have used. please see the following code

```
<div class="box1">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box d">
     </div>
</div>
```

the following will be the jquery lines of code

```
$('.box').mouseenter(function(e) {
$(this).css({'opacity': 0});
});
$('.box').mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).css({'opacity': 1});
});
```

and the css

```
.box{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}
```